# Modify Levenshtein-Distance to ignore order

Tags: python, algorithm, levenshtein-distance, edit-distance

I'm looking to compute the the Levenshtein-distance between sequences containing up to 6 values. **The order of these values should not affect the distance.**

How would I implement this into the iterative or recursive algorithm?

Example:

```
# Currently 
>>> LDistance('dog', 'god')
2

# Sorted
>>> LDistance('dgo', 'dgo')
0

# Proposed
>>> newLDistance('dog', 'god')
0
```

'dog' and 'god' have the exact same letters, sorting the strings before hand will return the desired result. However this doesn't work all the time:

```
# Currently 
>>> LDistance('doge', 'gold')
3

# Sorted
>>> LDistance('dego', 'dglo')
2

# Proposed
>>> newLDistance('doge', 'gold')
1
```

'doge' and 'gold' have 3/4 matching letters and so should return a distance of 1.
Here is my current recursive code:

```
def mLD(s, t):
    memo = {}
    def ld(s, t):
        if not s: return len(t)
        if not t: return len(s)
        if s[0] == t[0]: return ld(s[1:], t[1:])
        if (s, t) not in memo:
            l1 = ld(s, t[1:])
            l2 = ld(s[1:], t)
            l3 = ld(s[1:], t[1:])
            memo[(s,t)] = 1 + min(l1, l2, l3)
        return memo[(s,t)]
    return ld(s, t)
```

**EDIT:** Followup question: [Adding exceptions to Levenshtein-Distance-like algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459196/adding-exceptions-to-levenshtein-distance-like-algorithm)

Comment: Much simpler solution: write a function that just sorts both input strings and then calls LDistance in the normal way.

Comment: Even simpler than @EdCottrell's (already good) suggestion: Count character frequencies, separately for each string.  Then add up the frequency differences, and divide the final sum by 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the Levenshtein machinery for this.

```
import collections
def distance(s1, s2):
    cnt = collections.Counter()
    for c in s1:
        cnt[c] += 1
    for c in s2:
        cnt[c] -= 1
    return sum(abs(diff) for diff in cnt.values()) // 2 + \
        (abs(sum(cnt.values())) + 1) // 2   # can be omitted if len(s1) == len(s2)
```

Comment: Good approach, but I don't think the `//2` is correct in all cases. E.g., if you added two characters to a word, the distance should still be 2, not 1. I think it's `abs(sum(...))`, i.e. have too-many and too-few characters balance each other out... not, that's not right either...

Comment: Fixed it by adding a term for insert/delete.

Comment: Thanks! I was so caught up with learning Edit-distance algorithms that I overlooked collections. How would I add exceptions for items I deem similar, e.g. 'K' and 'C' are so similar that I want them to be worth 0.5 distance instead of 1?

Comment: @Luis That's trickier. Maybe ask a new question, with this one as context? You're probably going to end up needing a general matching algorithm, unfortunately, unless the exceptions have a nice structure.

Comment: I've edited the post linking to the new question. Hope it's clear enough

Answer (score 1):

Why not just count how many letters are in common, and find and answer from this? For each character calculate its frequency, then for each string calculate how many "extra" characters it has based on frequencies, and take maximum of these "extra".

Pseudocode:

```
for c in s1:
    cnt1[c]++
for c in s2:
    cnt2[c]++
extra1 = 0
extra2 = 0
for c in all_chars:
    if cnt1[c]>cnt2[c]
        extra1 += cnt1[c]-cnt2[c]
    else
        extra2 += cnt2[c]-cnt1[c]
return max(extra1, extra2)
```

Answer (score 0):

this might be late but I think it can help someone and I also still looking an improvement.
The challenge I had was:

1. match_function('kigali rwanda','rwanda kigali') probable match percentage should be 100%
2. match_function('kigali','ligaki') probable match percentage should be +50%
   ...
   I wrote a funny function in T-SQL using cross join and Levenstein and it helped at some point but I still need an improvement:

   ```
    Create FUNCTION [dbo].[GetPercentageMatch](@left  VARCHAR(100),@right VARCHAR(100))
    RETURNS DECIMAL
    AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @returnvalue DECIMAL(5, 2);
    DECLARE @list1 TABLE(value VARCHAR(50));
    declare @count1 int, @count2 int, @matchPerc int;
    INSERT INTO @list1 (value) select value from STRING_SPLIT(@left, ' ');

    DECLARE @list2 TABLE(value VARCHAR(50));
    INSERT INTO @list2 (value) select * from STRING_SPLIT(@right, ' ');

    select @count1 = count(*) from @list1
    select @count2 = count(*) from @list2

    select @matchPerc = (r3.percSum/case when @count1 > @count2 then @count1 else @count2 end) from (
    select count(r2.l1) rCount, sum(r2.perc) percSum from(
    select r.t1, r.t2, r.distance, (100-((r.distance*100)/(case when len(r.t1) > len(r.t2) then len(r.t1) else len(r.t2) end))) perc, len(r.t1) l1,len(r.t2)l2 from
    (select 
    isnull(t1.value,'') t1, 
    isnull(t2.value,'') t2, 
    [dbo].[LEVENSHTEIN](isnull(t1.value,''),isnull(t2.value,'')) distance
    from @list1 t1 cross join @list2 t2 ) as r
    ) r2
    ) r3

    return case when @matchPerc > 100 then 100 else @matchPerc end
    END;
   ```