# Adding exceptions to Levenshtein-Distance-like algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, counter, levenshtein-distance, edit-distance

I'm trying to compute how similar a sequence of up to 6 variables are. Currently I'm using a Collections Counter to return the frequency of different variables  as my edit-distance.

**By default, the distance in editing a variable (add/sub/change) is either 1 or 0. I'd like to change the distance depending on the variable and what value I set for that variable.**

So I can say certain variables are similar to other variables, and provide a value for how similar they are. 
I also want to say certain variables are worth less or more distance than usual.

Here is my previous post as context: [Modify Levenshtein-Distance to ignore order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32456943/modify-levenshtein-distance-to-ignore-order)

Example:

```
# 'c' and 'k' are quite similar, so their distance from eachother is 0.5 instead of 1
>>> groups = {['c','k'] : 0.5}

# the letter 'e' is less significant, and 'x' is very significant
>>> exceptions = {'e': 0.3, 'x': 1.5}

>>> distance('woke', 'woc')
0.8
```

Explanation:

```
woke
k -> c = 1
woce
-e = 1
woc
Distance = 2

# With exceptions:
woke
k -> c = 0.5
woce
-e = 0.3
woc
Distance = 0.8
```

**How could I achieve this? Would this be possible to implement with this Counter algorithm?**

Current code (thank you David Eisenstat)

```
def distance(s1, s2):
    cnt = collections.Counter()
    for c in s1:
        cnt[c] += 1
    for c in s2:
        cnt[c] -= 1
    return sum(abs(diff) for diff in cnt.values()) // 2 + \
        (abs(sum(cnt.values())) + 1) // 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up dividing the process into a few stages then iterating through the strings for each stage. I'm not sure if its as efficient as it could be but it works.

Summing up what I was trying to achieve (in relation to Edit-distance algorithms)

- Distance from one letter to another is 1. `change j -> k = 1`
- 0 being no difference at all. e.g. `change j -> j = 0`
- Similar letters can be worth less than 1 (specified by me) e.g. `c` and `k` sound the same, therefore  `c, k = 0.5`, `change c -> k = 0.5`
- Certain letters could be worth more or less (specified by me) e.g. `x` is uncommon so I want it to have more weight, `x = 1.4`,  `change x -> k = 1.4`

Created 2 dictionaries, 1 for **similar** letters, 1 for **exceptions**

1. **Populate Counter** -
   Iterate through both strings
2. **Match similar items** - Iterate string1, if in similar dict, iterate string2, if in similar dict
3. **Update Counter** - remove similar items,
4. **Find Distance** - add up absolute frequencies, account for difference in string length
5. **Include exceptions distance** - Account for exception values based on frequency of letters

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this is the [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem). You have a set of characters from one string, a set of characters fro another string, and a set of costs for assigning a character from one string to a character in another string. You can add some dummy characters to both strings to treat the add/delete operations.

There are many known algorithms for the assignment problem. One of them is the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm), the linked Wikipedia article contains links to some of the implementations. Other method is [reducing the assignment problem to maxflow-mincost problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem#Minimum_weight_bipartite_matching), which you can find simpler to adjust for add/delete operations.